# How to safely convert / parse HTML and other symbols to simple text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I have a chat application developed using NodeJs and HTML. Now, all I want that if I type something like:

> 1. Hi > how?
> 2. `<div style="color:red"></div>`
> 3. & could you

All of them should be displayed as they are. And HTML tags shouldn't be rendered and text shouldn't be red. In short, the output should be like:

> 1. Hi > how?
> 2. `<div style="color:red"></div>`
> 3. & could you

I looked for some old questions and answers here, but I want to know how major sites like Facebook, WhatsApp, Quora do such things? Just like converting > and < to &lt and &gt or using a method like `replace()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<xmp>` tag. Everything inside it will be plain text, rather than HTML.

```html
<xmp><div style="color:red">hi</div></xmp>
```

Alternatively, you could use the `<plaintext>` tag, but that doesn't have a close tag, so would be annoying to use.

```html
<plaintext><div style="color:red">hi</div></plaintext>
```

**Edit:**

You can use some JavaScript and jQuery to achive this:

```js
var text = $('.container').html();
$('.container').text(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"><div style="color:red">hi</div></div>
```

This grabbs the html inside the `.container` div, and converts it to plain text.

Comment: I understand this thing. But when you inspect HTML for Facebook chat message divs, their status fields and WhatsApp chat bubbles, you don't see anything like <pre> <xmp>. How do they do? Any idea?

Comment: @VikasKumar How's my answer?

Comment: Inserting text instead of html is good approach, but I have to insert HTML to. If you know, a chat-bubble is HTML. The thing is message text inside that chat bubble. I wanted that thing to be converted. I have solved it using `&lt` and `&gt` instead. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. I already knew what you told. I upvoted it. Still thanks.